# XNA textures with native library

Tags: c#, 3d, xna, pinvoke, direct3d

I've been attempting to use Seefront 3D API with XNA. Seefront delivers 3D panels to f.ex. Sony to provide glasses-free 3D. These panels refract light, with one beam of light ending up in your one eye and one beam in the other.

How this basically works is that eye tracking software in the API figures out where both your eyes are. The API calls then take over the rendering: a call to sfdx_setTextures then takes 2 IDirect3DTexture9* textures, which are then processed by a pixel shader in the API.

In an earlier C++ project, I've added functionality to MPC-HC that does exactly this: https://github.com/atlaste/mpc-hc/tree/master/src/filters/renderer/VideoRenderers .

Now I'm attempting to do new fancy things with XNA and ran into a snitch. Unfortunately I cannot share the Seefront DLL's; they're not mine to give away... code will have to do (I've removed checks etc here).

The DLL is first loaded using LoadLibrary with some boring calls to enable interop.

```
this.dllHandle = Win32NativeMethods.LoadLibrary(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Sony\SeeFront3D\seefront_ilace_dx.dll");

// Initialize; LoadFunction basically calls GetProcAddress
this.CreateInstance = LoadFunction<CreateInstanceFunc>(dllHandle, "sfdx_createInstance");
this.StartTrackerUpdate = LoadFunction<StartTrackerUpdateFunc>(dllHandle, "sfdx_startTrackerUpdate");
this.SetTextures = LoadFunction<SetTexturesFunc>(dllHandle, "sfdx_setTextures");
this.SetTextureSize = LoadFunction<SetTextureSizeFunc>(dllHandle, "sfdx_setTextureSize");
// etc...
```

The result are a bunch of calls that are wrapped in delegates. Initialization happens by calling CreateInstance with a IDirect3DDevice9* and StartTrackerUpdate. This is the first point where XNA doesn't give us what we need, so the API is initialized as follows:

```
// Get pComPtr from device
var ptr = device.GetType().GetField("pComPtr", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
var d3ddevice = (Pointer)ptr.GetValue(device);
var ptrValue = Pointer.Unbox(d3ddevice);

// Create seefront instance
this.instance = CreateInstance((IDirect3DDevice9*)ptrValue);
StartTrackerUpdate(instance);
```

After calling these two, the camera is enabled, which is an indication that it's alive. This leaves the last thing to wrap: the calls to SetTexture. Because it's an array of pointers that's passed to the API and assumably not copied, I allocate a few pointers on the heap (Disposed with IDisposable), and again get the IDirect3DTexture9* pointers by a messy GetComPtr call:

```
// initialization:
realTextures = (IDirect3DTexture9**)Marshal.AllocHGlobal(IntPtr.Size * 2);

// ...

private IDirect3DTexture9** realTextures;

public void RenderFrame(Texture texture1, Texture texture2)
{
    MethodInfo textureMethod = typeof(Texture).GetMethod("GetComPtr", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

    var ptr = (Pointer)textureMethod.Invoke(texture1, null);
    realTextures[0] = (IDirect3DTexture9*)Pointer.Unbox(ptr);

    ptr = (Pointer)textureMethod.Invoke(texture2, null);
    realTextures[1] = (IDirect3DTexture9*)Pointer.Unbox(ptr);

    SetTextures(instance, realTextures, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1);
    Render(instance);
    Sync(instance);
}
```

All the mess above is wrapped in a small class called SeeFront3D that is called from the XNA application.

Next thing is to render something in XNA. Because the API accepts two textures, I basically create these in the Draw phase of the 'game' using the method described in http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/Series3/Render_to_texture.php .

This code looks like this:

```
private SeeFront3D sf3d;
private RenderTarget2D[] eyeTextures;
private int currentEyeTexture = 0;

protected override void LoadContent()
{
    InitializeModel();
    InitializeEffect();

    if (EnableSeefront3D)
    {
        sf3d = new SeeFront3D(GraphicsDevice, Window);
    }

    eyeTextures = new RenderTarget2D[4];
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        eyeTextures[i] = new RenderTarget2D(GraphicsDevice, 1980, 1080, true, GraphicsDevice.DisplayMode.Format, DepthFormat.Depth24Stencil8);
    }
}

// ...

protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
    // render right eye; normally you render both eyes, but this is for testing.
    GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(rightEye);
    GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
    Render();
    GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(null);

    GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

    if (EnableSeefront3D)
    {
        sf3d.SetTextureDimensions(1980, 1080);
        sf3d.RenderFrame(rightEye, rightEye);
        // Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0)); // used for debugging
    }
    else
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
        using (SpriteBatch sprite = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice))
        {
            sprite.Begin();
            sprite.Draw(rightEye, new Vector2(0, 0), null, Color.White, 0, new Vector2(0, 0), 0.4f, SpriteEffects.None, 1);
            sprite.End();
        }
    }

    base.Draw(gameTime);
}

private void Render()
{
    foreach (EffectPass pass in basicEffect.CurrentTechnique.Passes)
    {
        pass.Apply();
    }

    GraphicsDevice.Indices = indexBuffer;
    GraphicsDevice.SetVertexBuffer(vertexBuffer);
    graphics.GraphicsDevice.DrawIndexedPrimitives(
        PrimitiveType.TriangleList, 0, 0, this.vertexBuffer.VertexCount, 0, this.indexBuffer.IndexCount / 3);
}
```

Of course I've tried different variations such as calling 'clear' with one color on the left eye and calling it with another on the right eye, etc.

What happens is the following:

- Clear seems to work fine. If you fill two eyes with two colors, you get exactly that.
- If you alterate the colors, it will still work fine.
- You can see the pixel shaders of Seefront doing their job. If you change position, the pixels on the screen change position as well.
- If you set the EnableSeefront3D flag to 'false', you can see that the rendering works

However (*the issue*):

- The first iteration of the draw loop, you get a 'gray' screen.
- The 3D model is only rendered the 2nd iteration of the draw loop (I figured this out with the 'sleep' call)
- After the 2nd iteration of the draw loop, only the background (from 'clear') is rendered; the 3D model is gone.

I personally think the first frame is a small bug in the SeeFront libraries, and definitely something I can live with.

If you start the application, it looks like this:
[image: Second frame (correct)]

[image: Later frames (3d model is gone)]

You can clearly see that the Seefront libraries are called judging by the garbled images; the 3D model is also clearly gone after the first frame.

Any suggestions what can go wrong c.q. how to solve this?

Comment: Are you sure the resolution is `1980 x 1080` and not `1920 x 1080` .. ?

Comment: @KenKin Nice catch! Too bad it doesn't seem to matter, the behavior is the same.

Comment: Contact the vendor. I you have problems with the interop we can help. But this is a problem with the library. You need vendor support.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Actually I'm not 100% sure if it's a problem with interop, a problem with the vendor, or the way I use DirectX textures. After all, the C++ implementation works just fine. Either way it doesn't matter: Sony is of no use and Seefront doesn't support customers directly...

Comment: First step is to narrow it down. Is it a problem with interop or not.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Well, that's exactly the problem, isn't it? Judging by the garbled images the interop is working. From the spritebatch you can also assume that the rendering itself is correct (otherwise you wouldn't get an image); however, since spritebatch uses XNA and not interop, it might be wrong in the middle (with the comptr retrieved with reflection). Strangely the 'clear' call is rendered. I an attempt to remove the 'middle' thing, I tried creating an additional texture and copying all data from the 'righteye' to the new texture -- no change. You can see why I'm lost.

Comment: What might happen is that the API creates a lock in DirectX on the textures. To check that, I added the buffer with 4 textures; you should see a different behavior if there's a lock -- but the behavior is the same. I even explicitly allocate the IDirect3DTexture9 array using Marshal to ensure the GC doesn't move around the memory of the array (after exitting a fixed block). So... can you see any more things I can check?

Answer (score 3):

**Grey frame**

If your grey color matches `#CDCDCDCD` (http://www.colorhexa.com/cdcdcd , (mind the possible alpha value)) your textures (memory) data isn't set yet. If so, changes are big you'll get a very random first frame if you compile this to a release version.

The compiler uses this mark (0xCD), in debug mode, to mark the memory as 'clean'.

http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/w-p/win32/tutorials/article.php/c9535/Inside-CRT-Debug-Heap-Management.htm

In release mode, this is usually skipped by the optimization and you'll be left with a big bunch of garbage.

But if, as you said, as this is an external library, you might want to check if you are using a `debug` version.

To fix this, you'll somehow need to update the texture first before presenting. Also, it might lead you to a significant flaw in your code. So it is worth to check out, how or when the texture is available.

**After 2nd iteration**
Still working on this one, so please be gentle

So you're extracting your `IDirect3DDevice9` pointer from your `GraphicsDevice`. That's good.

But with the rendering:

```
GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(rightEye);
GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
Render();
GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(null);

GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

if (EnableSeefront3D)
{
    sf3d.SetTextureDimensions(1980, 1080);
    sf3d.RenderFrame(rightEye, rightEye);
}
```

It confuses me a bit:

- first you set and clear the rightEye render target and render some stuff.
- then you put the original backbuffer back as rendertarget, and clear this as well.
- after that you'll let the external library render to the native device, using the textures as input.

This last thing concerns me, does the Seefront 3D Renders to the texture or to the backbuffer? 
If it renders to the texture, with for example the pixel shader you mentioned, there is nothing that actual presents the rightEye texture. My guess is it renders to the backbuffer, so; still working on it but it's worth to check.

Furthermore
`// render right eye; normally you render both eyes, but this is for testing.`.

I would strongly discourage this. If the internal render is optimized for parallel processing (something the GPU likes), there might be some `locking` or `dirty region` issues because different read/write operations are applied to the same texture. As the actual implementation is unknown, it's better to be safe in this case.

A last note on the

```
sf3d.SetTextureDimensions(1980, 1080);
```

call.

In native DirectX this is a no go. The memory allocated for a texture is determined when the texture is created. Stuff like `FORMAT`, `MemoryPool`, `Size` etc. is set when you create the texture. A re-size would certainly lead to a re-creation of the texture.

As I think of it: it might be interesting, if possible, to see in what memory pool the rightEye rendertarget lives. In the native directX library there are some restrictions for the texture updates. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172584%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172625%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

```
D3DUSAGE_RENDERTARGET

The resource will be a render target. D3DUSAGE_RENDERTARGET can only be used with 
D3DPOOL_DEFAULT.
```

Comment: I'm confused that it matters the code is post or not. Is it because of the license used in the source?

Comment: @KenKin: Well, the functions mentioned are defined in the OP's class. If, for example, `Render(instance)` is defined by the OP i am wondering what it does, as it seems there is an error in the rendering of the textures.

Comment: @KenKin: sorry, my bad. I overlooked the dll imports. I'll edit the post. Thanks.

Comment: @Stefan thanks; let's see. It's not #CDCDCDCD for sure, it's pretty damn blue... and debug mode doesn't really change anything (as expected since it's in lib). Yes, Seefront 3D Renders to backbuffer. If I remove the clear of the backbuffer, the screen turns dark blue... funny, not what I was expecting...

Comment: @Stefan I've been looking around for the pool it resides in but so far haven't found the answer. Sounds plausible though; mixing native with managed directx might give these problems. You have any more information where/how to look perhaps?

Comment: @Stefan de Bruijn: I will have a look around and will contact you if I found something.

Comment: @Stefan FYI it appears that Sony distributes the Seefront DLL's through the 'drivers' in SOAOTH-00268817-1040.EXE (available on http://esupport.sony.com/US/p/swu-download.pl?mdl=VPCSB3AFX&upd_id=7710&os_group_id=6 ) . This will probably make things easier.